# Can ппц word use for a good manner?

Tags: узус

What it means in Russian " ого ппц! милый." Imagine one girl write this as an answer to her friend who sent Justin Bieber video when he is singing in a car.

[image]

I want to understand here also full meaning of ого ппц! милый. Is that something like " Woow, so cutee!!" or what. Also, what this word used for in here -> милый ?

Answer (score 8):

This `ппц` is an abbreviated way to write the word `пипéц` (pee-PETS) which is in its turn a euphemism for the word `пиздéц` (peez-DETS), an obscene way to say "God damn!" or "Fucking shit!" It's an exclamation and it has a wide range of meanings, a whole spectrum of them, begining with the expression of admiration and finishing with complete dislike, rejection, and condemnation of the subject matter. In any way, it expresses a strong emotion. In your sentence, it's admiration.

Answer (score 3):

There is an obscene word `пиздец` (from the obscene root `пизда` - cunt). According to wiktionary it means

```
1. (vulgar) extreme degree of anything.

    1 000 000 — э́то пизде́ц ско́лько де́нег!‎ ― One million is hell of a lot of money!

2. (vulgar, sometimes humorous) extremely undesirable situation

3. (vulgar) death, curtains.
```

There are two euphemisms of this taboo word: `песец` (mostly for meanings 2 and 3) and `пипец` (also with slightly different spectrum of meanings). `Ппц` is short of `пипец` (like `thx` means `thanks`).  See https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%86 for it meanings.

In this sentence it means something like "wow".

Answer (score 0):

So, this word was entered in common lexicon after few seasons of a dumb TV sitcom "Univer". It was been reguraliry pronounced by a silly person, Allochka. Then, if you will use in your speak the word ппц, your familiar have suspicted you in poor taste (and in dumb-TV-show addiction).

Comment: Word ппц was a thing when I was a kid and it was like 20 years before any Russian sitcom as aired.

Comment: @shabunc: didn't have you down as someone who was a kid 20 years before _Кабачок "13 стульев"_ was aired!